# How Do I Accept JSON in Web API 2.0 and Return Same?

Tags: json, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

I'm not a VB developer but attempting to help a coworker.

Trying to get a simple example using Web API 2.0 and VB to accept a JSON POST, and return it, mapped as a custom object.

The included template in VS 2013 includes a POST example subroutine but no return.  My attempt does not create the value upon posting a JSON object via rest client (postman) and then of course returns null. Setting header with accepts Application/JSON and RAW JSON HTTP POST.  Below is the change I made to the included example controller and I added the class.  My understanding is that Web API should be able to map a posted JSON object to a custom class and handle all the serialization.  I'm obviously missing something.

```
    Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As Value)
    Return value
    End Function
```

Note: Value is simple class with 2 public fields

```
Public Class Value

Public firstName As String
Public lastName As String

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you post a JSON object to a web api, the controller automatically maps the keys with the Model properties and on success when you receive a JSON object, it will be treated as keyvalue pair with keys as your Model Property name and Value is thier value they contained like

Javascript:

```
var data= {
 firstName: $("#Name").val(),
 lastName: $("#lName").val()
 };

 //Convert javascript object to JSON object
 var DTO = JSON.stringify(data);
 $.ajax({
 url: 'api/product', //calling Web API controller product
 cache: false,
 type: 'POST',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 data: DTO,
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (returnedData) {
 $.each(object, function (key, val) {
   // do anything with your key val pair});
 }
 });
```

Controller: In controller you will see that on post the `_mode`l get filled with the data you sent via json object: that is firstName and lastName properties gets filled

```
Public function PostData(_model as Value)
        Return Json(_model)
End Function
```

Comment: When using the Json(_model) I received an exception stating to check for a circular reference.  If I just returned the _model, it seems to respond correctly now.

Comment: Yes resolved with that caveat, Returning object vs Json(object).  Thank you.